# Selection box model with typescript and knockout (foreach)

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

I'm working with Knockout and Typescript. I have a form that has multiple input and one select tag. For input data it's easy to bind data just via it's name. However for select tag (dropdown list) it's not so obvious. 
I try to set default option for dropdown list for multiple objects in foreach.

I followed this way :  [Selection box model with typescript and knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413635/selection-box-model-with-typescript-and-knockout)

my exemplary Typescript:

```
export class ViewModel {
choices = ko.observable([
    { id: 1, hour: "01:00", choice: false },
    { id: 2, hour: "02:00", choice: false },
    { id: 3, hour: "03:00", choice: false },
    { id: 4, hour: "04:00", choice: false },
    { id: 5, hour: "05:00", choice: false },
    { id: 6, hour: "06:00", choice: false },
    { id: 7, hour: "07:00", choice: false },
    { id: 8, hour: "08:00", choice: false },
    { id: 9, hour: "09:00", choice: false },
    { id: 10, hour: "10:00", choice: false },
]);
selectedChoice = ko.observable(10);
selectedHours = ko.observable([1, 5, 7]);

constructor() {
    this.config = new ServiceConfigurationModel();
    this.getConfiguration();
    this.selectedChoice.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        alert("the new value is " + newValue);
    });
}
}
```

when I have this line in HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options: choices, optionsText: 'hour', optionsValue: 'id',  value: selectedChoice"></select>
```

however when I want to repeat it for each selectedHours array using `<!-- ko foreach: selectedHours() -->` it doesn't work

Do you have any hint how to set this option for multiple drop-down list without repeating whole code?

Thank you in advance for any help <3

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [selectedOptions](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html) binding?

Btw, your `choices` observable should be an observableArray. And also `selectedHours`.

```js
function viewmodel(){
  this.choices = ko.observableArray([
    { id: 1, hour: "01:00", choice: false },
    { id: 2, hour: "02:00", choice: false },
    { id: 3, hour: "03:00", choice: false },
    { id: 4, hour: "04:00", choice: false },
    { id: 5, hour: "05:00", choice: false },
    { id: 6, hour: "06:00", choice: false },
    { id: 7, hour: "07:00", choice: false },
    { id: 8, hour: "08:00", choice: false },
    { id: 9, hour: "09:00", choice: false },
    { id: 10, hour: "10:00", choice: false },
  ]);
  //selectedChoice = ko.observable(10);
  this.selectedHours = ko.observableArray([1, 5, 7]);
  this.selectedHours.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        //alert("the new value is " + newValue);
        console.log("the new value is " + newValue);
  });
  this.clear = function(){
      console.clear();
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(viewmodel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: choices, 
                   optionsText: 'hour', 
                   optionsValue: 'id',  
                   selectedOptions: selectedHours" 
        multiple="true" 
        style="height: 150px"></select>
 <button data-bind="click: clear" style="float: right">Clear</button>
```

Comment: Ray, Thank you very very much for your comment! It's a nice example  but I'm looking for MULTIPLE DROPDOWN LISTS, not multiple values selected on one list. 
The thing is that I work on creating form based on some .json data and I need to bind proper data. Each form will have the same schema - it'll contain multiple inputs, checkboxes, but also one dropdown list (select) and 2radio buttons. I don't want to write multiple forms in HTML. I try to use Knockout foreach to iterate over whole .json and display data in the form
that's the point where I have a problem with multiple dropdown lists